# using express response into custom callbacks of Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Mongoose and Firebase along with Express and since sometime I have to still go on with the same callback function of mongoose but with different parameters or after a firebase callback I was thinking of use a custom callback named function. My issue is that since I need to send a response in this function I need to use the `res` variable from the Express callback which is not available. So how can still use the Express `res`?

This snippet below generates a run time error of `undefined variable res` into `userCallback` (pseudocode). I wonder how can I use the same code twice in situations like this one?

```
function userCallback(err, user) {
    // some other processing
    res.json({});
}

router.get('/:username', function (req, res, next) {
    let idToken = req.header('idToken');
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken, true)
        .then(function (decodedToken) {
            let email = req.query.email;
            if (!email) {
                User.findOne({
                    username: req.params.username
                }, userCallback);
            } else {
                admin.auth().getUserByEmail(req.params.username).then((user_firebase) => {
                    User.findOne({
                        uid: user_firebase.uid
                    }, userCallback);
                }).catch((error) => {
                    res.json({
                        result: false,
                        error
                    });
                });
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            res.json({
                result: false,
                error
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Thecave3, can I confirmed with you that you tried responding to the HTTP request by using res inside your userCallback callback? May I ask if your userCallback is your own callback instead of mongoose's standard callback?

Comment: Hi @CodeCodey, yes, i'm trying to respond inside userCallback and yes userCallBack is my own callback which is passed into mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using findOne(), you have to use its callback (not your customized callback) which is

```
User.findOne({<search_params>}, (err, document)=>{ 
    // this callback is specific to mongoose API and you have to follow the parameters
    // err is the error occurred when running findOne()
    // document is returned document passed back to you by findOne()
    // when your customized callback uses res, it had no knowledge of it in its current scope
})
```

The reason why you are unable to return the res is because the res was not passed into your customized callback as a parameter. Thus your custom callback does not know res exists! I suggest you handle the response at function(decodeToken) level instead / you could try passing res into your callback as the last parameter see if it helps.

```
User.findOne({}, (err, document, res){} // Don't think this will work
```